# How many types of speakers had android device?

Tags: android, audio

My question is - I need to know how many types of speaker has android phone? I mean for example regular device has one speaker and one microphone. But about speaker for example when user speak by phone hold the device near a ear, so speaker in a low volume, but also user can tap on Speaker mode and now you can hear also sound from speaker but loud. And also there one more option if user playback a music you can also hear it loud but with better quality.

Question is - is this speaker in low volume, speaker in loud volume and speaker that playback music is this one the same speaker or is it different speakers? Or maybe it is the same speaker but playback goes in different mode? Or different types?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard way to check the speaker configuration on Android. You would need to check the manufacturer specification of the handset.

The difference in quality between the voice and the music likely is due to the compression the voice undergoes in order to be transmitted in real time. The music can stream or buffer and thus can have higher fidelitiy. 
It is unlikely that the difference is due specifically to the speaker configuration.